# Hosting a Odoo 9 onsite with Hyper V- Security concerns

Tags: ubuntu, hyper-v, windows-server-2012-r2, odoo

I have a small business network:

- Hyper V Host (2012R2)
- VM-Active Directory (2012R2)
- VM -application, print, etc server (2012R2)
- Several client pcs, some on domain, some not, all running Windows 7 or later.
- Router / modem for internet and pstn phones

I am looking at moving to hosting our own Odoo (openERP) server on Ubuntu as another VM. Odoo has a e-commerce / shopfront website that customers can access built in (although actual payment I believe is handled through paypal etc). I am not opposed to hosting it on Amazon EC2, but I would prefer to host it locally.

I would like to know (or be pointed to resources)

- by having that odoo shopfront port open to the internet, am I inviting security issues?  Would hosting Odoo on that hyperV server be compromising the rest of the network?

If no..

- What kind of security guides should I follow outside of https://askubuntu.com/questions/146775/what-can-be-done-to-secure-ubuntu-server and nginx?
- What kind of security should I be setting up regarding the rest of the network: the hyperV host, VMs, router settings etc?